# Is there a way to access rendered content in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, layout, jekyll

In Jekyll, is there any way to access the rendered content of a post from another page?

Here's the scenario: Suppose I wanted to create a blog index page listing a bunch of posts. Each post uses a different layout (text, photo, tweet, etc). Is there a way to get Jekyll to render each post with the layout specified inside of that post and then hand me the rendered content so that I can put it into a summary page?

(I'm 97% sure I saw this exact question asked and answered somewhere here on Stack Overflow, but I cannot for the life of me find it. If anyone could point me to it, I would be most grateful! Of course, original solutions are also appreciated!)

(Edited to make it clear that I want *dynamic* access to rendered content. Not after the fact in the _sites directory, but while building the site.)

Answer (score 1):

`post.layout`is the layout of one post, it's default is `post`
So, i think, you can do this

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.layout == 'layout1' %}
     do something, such as put it into an array ...
  {% else if post.layout == 'layout2' %} // here 'else if' may not correct liquid syntax
     do something else
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```