# Is there a way in Jekyll to retrieve the number of pictures in a post's content?

Tags: image, post, jekyll

In a Jekyll's post I've seen how to count words with `include.content | number_of_words` but I was wondering if there was a way to count pictures in the **content**?

I do know there is a way to get a featured image if I add it to the frontmatter like:

```
feature-img: "img/foobar.png"
```

Per my searches I did see `post.layout` but I am unable to find if there is a way to get the count of images in a post's content. When I search to see if this has been asked or someone has brought this up in Jekyll issues the only I do not get any results but I have read:

- [Is there a way to access rendered content in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157260/is-there-a-way-to-access-rendered-content-in-jekyll)
- [How to retrieve the current post index number in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073090/how-to-retrieve-the-current-post-index-number-in-jekyll)
- [How to include all files in a folder in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035330/how-to-include-all-files-in-a-folder-in-jekyll)

I could see if I was going to build a gallery for a post adding the images to the frontmatter like:

```
---
layout: post
title: "This is a title"
images:
  - url: "img/foo.png"
    alt: "Enter the foo"
    title: "apart of foo"

  - url: "img/bar.png"
    alt: "Enter the bar"
    title: "apart of bar"
---
```

but the images are spread throughout the content. I guess I could hard code it to every post in the frontmatter like:

```
---
image-count: 4
---
```

but I think that just bloats the frontmatter. In Jekyll is there a way to get the post's images count dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a way to get the count of images in a post without hard coding the image count in the front matter:

```
{% assign postPics = include.content | split: "<img" | size %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably split the content, like this:

```
{% assign contentparts = content | split: '<img' %}
{% assing amountofimages = contentparts | minus:1 %}
```

Then use:

```
{{ amountofimages }}
```

Note that I did not test this.